# XSLT, XML: HTML Table content not displaying

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have this XML:

```
<table title = "Fuzzy Bunnies">
    <tgroup cols = "2">
        <tbody>
            <colspec colname = "Bunny Name"></colspec>
            <colspec colname = "Bunny Traits"></colspec>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    Bugs Bunny
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    Likes to mess with people. Known for saying "What's up, Doc?"
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    Easter Bunny
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    Brings candy and/or hides eggs on Easter. 
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    Little Bunny Foo Foo
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    Used to pick up field mice and bop them on the head. Turned into a goon by the good fairy.
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    Roger Rabbit
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    Toon who was framed.
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    Peter Rabbit
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    Ridiculously cute. Loses his jacket and shoes stealing veggies.
                </entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

and this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{font-family:Arial;font-size:.95em;}
            p{font-family:Arial;font-size:.95em;text-align:left;}
    h1{font-size:1.25em;color:Navy;font-weight:bold;}
    h2{font-size:1em;}
    h3{font-size:.75em;font-weight:bold;}
    .caption{font-weight:bold;text-align:center;}
    .graphic{text-align:center;}
    table{border-collapse:collapse;}
    table,th,td{border:1px solid gray;}
    th{color:white;background-color:Navy;}
    td{font-size:.9em;}
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "table">
<table>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Fuzzy Bunnies</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Bunny Name</th>
    <th>Bunny Traits</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl-apply-templates select = "row"/>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "row">
<tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="entry"/>
</tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "entry">
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select ="."/>
</td>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want an HTML table with the headings listed in the template, and each entry in its own cell. When I open the file in Firefox or IE, I get the table header, but no content.

A couple things to note.  One, this is a chunk of a larger XML document.  The only thing I've cut out of the XSLT is templates for nodes that aren't part of the table. Likewise, for the XML, I've cut it down to just the table.  Another is that the XML is formatted based on a standard which I can't change, so any changes need to be to the XSLT.

I have looked at the other table questions and I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have very strange patterns and select expression, for instance why do you want to output for all nodes `match="@*|node()"` a complete HTML document structure? Usual you want to do that for `match="/"` or `match="/*"`.

As for the problem, the `row` elements are not children of the `table` but are nested further down the structure, so doing `<xsl-apply-templates select = "row"/>` in the `table` template will not process the rows, you need `select=".//row"`.

Of course there can be further problems in the part you have "cut out of the XSLT is templates for nodes that aren't part of the table", if there you do not make sure that processing reaches the `table` element(s) then the template will never be used.

Comment: Good catch on the structure, but it looks like there's something else going on. (Changing select = "row" to select = ".//row" didn't fix the output.  As for the initial template, that was pulled from an answer to a different Stack Overflow question (which I'm not finding right now), regarding how to display links and formatting within paragraphs.  It may well need to be changed to something else.

Let me know if you need to see the full XSLT and/or XML, if you think that weirdness might be screwing up the table.

Comment: After playing with it a little more, I think what you caught *was* the whole issue.  Once I added additional templates for the nodes in between <table> and <row>, it worked perfectly.  (In that case, I'm still not sure why using ".//row" didn't work, though.)